# two insert...on duplicate key in one procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to use two simple insert...on duplicate key statements in one mysql procedure.
I have a view with some information containing the colomns **(user_id, lid_sinds, besparing)** which I want to transfer to wp_bp_xprofile_data **( field_id,  user_id, value)**. the lid_sinds column should have field_id 31 in the wp_bp_xprofile_data table and the besparing column should have field_id 32.

These are the two queries i use:
query 1

```
INSERT INTO wp_bp_xprofile_data
( field_id,  user_id, value)

SELECT 31, user_id,  lid_sinds
FROM  besparingen_lid

On duplicate KEY UPDATE 
wp_bp_xprofile_data.value=(SELECT besparingen_lid.lid_sinds
  FROM besparingen_lid
  WHERE besparingen_lid.user_id=wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id)
```

query 2:

```
 INSERT INTO wp_bp_xprofile_data
( field_id,  user_id, value)

SELECT 32, user_id,  besparing
FROM  besparingen_lid

On duplicate KEY UPDATE 
wp_bp_xprofile_data.value=(SELECT besparingen_lid.besparing
  FROM besparingen_lid
  WHERE besparingen_lid.user_id=wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id )
```

How can I combine these two queries into one procedure in MySQL? or is it possible to merge the two queries into one? I hope somebody can give me a hand here :)

edit: i tried merging the queries with union all:

```
INSERT INTO wp_bp_xprofile_data
( field_id,  user_id, value)

SELECT 31, user_id,  lid_sinds
FROM  besparingen_lid

 Union all

SELECT 32, user_id,  besparing
FROM  besparingen_lid

On duplicate KEY UPDATE 
wp_bp_xprofile_data.value=(SELECT CASE

WHEN wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id = 31 Then  besparingen_lid.lid_sinds
WHEN wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id = 32 Then  besparingen_lid.besparing

END

  FROM besparingen_lid, wp_bp_xprofile_data
  WHERE besparingen_lid.user_id=wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id )
```

I receive an error stating `#1054 - Unknown column 'wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id' in 'field list'`, while I am pretty sure that this column does exist because the two individual queries do work. any suggestions?

edit2: added wp_bp_xprofile_data at FROM. When i run the query for a second time it give me the following `error:#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row` . I am sure that the user_id and field_id combination in wp_bp_xprofile_data is unique, so i guess the error is actually caused by the case statement...any hints?

Comment: can't you do a `UNION?`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Rahul, I'm gonna try your suggestion right now..